# FB.Event.subscribe code not working

Tags: javascript, facebook

I am using this code to get the response:

```
<fb:like layout="button_count" notify="true" colorscheme="dark" href="http://www.fbrell.com"></fb:like>
<script>
  // this will fire when any of the like widgets are "liked" by the user
  FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
    alert('You liked ' + href, widget);
  });
</script>
```

It's not giving any response. Can anyone tell what wrong am i doing ?

Comment: Your sample is just working correctly. Do you have any errors on page before? Does number of likes increases once you pressing the "Like Button"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have the FB Like button appearing, so you must be including the SDK correctly, I was in exactly the same situation - all you're missing is setting the subscribe up in the fbAsyncInit() function.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function (targetUrl) {
        _gaq.push(['_trackSocial', 'facebook', 'like', targetUrl]);
    });
};
```

If you're doing this you don't need an application ID nor do you you need to use the FBML code, you can use the HTML5 inclusion code like `<div class='fb-like' data-href='...`

Answer (score 1):

1. You're missing the inclusion of the javascript SDK files.
2. You're missing the FB.init
3. You're not running your code within the fbAsyncInit() function.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ for more information.

Comment: You're not required to call to `FB.init` to subscribe for `edge.create` event.

Comment: Kewl, did not know that, but you are required to include the JS SDK to be able to call FB.Event.Subscribe, right?  And the code is not being called in the fbAsyncInit, so there might be an issue with timing of the async javascript loading. Also there is no "notify" attribute according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: Opps!! I just played with it at http://jsfiddle.net/dmcs/epgS6/1/ and found that the Event subscibe being called without FB.init causes the like plugin NOT to be rendered.

Comment: What I said is only correct for an `XFBML` version of Like Button if `#xfmbl=1` appended to JS-SDK javascript URL. http://jsfiddle.net/epgS6/2/

Comment: Ok, true.  However, the question above doesn't even have the js sdk, so I cannot assume they would have appended the #xfbml=1 querystring parameter.

Comment: `XFBML` tags (like `fb:like`) work only with JS-SDK included on page. And `FB.Event.subscribe` is part of JS-SDK. So probably OP have it. BTW, social widget generators always add snippet with JS-SDK inclusion. I'm not trying to convince here anything, just trying to inform about this option...

Comment: Yes, but none of that is included above in their question.  And I have fixed other people's problems many times in the past by having them add the JS SDK load script as well as ensure they place the event subscription code inside of the fbAsyncInit.  It seems to be a common mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Checklist:

(Im assuming you have setup the Javascript SDK)

run the FB linter on your url, errors here may stop it working

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Include this at the top of the page

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

If your liking an app, include on your app page

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="Your app id" />
```

Like button, change href to your link

```
<fb:like layout="button_count"  show_faces="false" height="21" href="http://facebook.com"></fb:like>
```

If its an app, FB prefers HTTPS

```
function init() {
       FB.init({
            appId: APP_ID,
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            oauth: true
        });

    //uncomment if required 
    //window.fbAsyncInit = function() { 
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
        function(response) {
            alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
        }
    );
   //}
}
init();
```

Comment: make sure you haven't liked then unliked the page multiple times, otherwise this behavior occurs